# Javascript 2d drawing in IE

Tags: javascript, 2d

I need to fill polygons with certain colors when they are clicked. Polygons are drawn on the background image. I'm using map and area tags to detect click on polygon and then using *moveTo()*, *lineTo()*, *closePath()* and *fill()* to draw filled polygon on the top.
Is it possible to use javascript drawing functions mentioned above in IE7, IE8 and IE9? Code works fine in firefox and chrome, but doesnt work in IE.

Is using canvas element the only possible way of drawing with javascript? I mean core javascript, without using third party libraries.

Comment: You could try SVG. Have you considered this?

Comment: @REsmond IE7 and 8 don't support SVG :(

Comment: [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) will use SVG on browser that have it and use a (slow) fallback mechanism for old IEs. Might be worth looking into..

Comment: There are various fallbacks for both canvas and SVG in IE. Google them!

Answer (score 0):

[RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com) is a library for working with SVG elements. 
It's great because it

1. provides support for older browsers by using VML
2. has an easy to use, well documented API for creating and animating SVG elements
3. has wrapper function for events, so it's easy to implement the onclick events you are talking about